# Ajax call Gives internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to show a progress bar image when I create an Excel file. I am using an ajax call to call my controller action method. It gives me Internal Server Error.
Here is my controller/Action method and Ajax call .....

```
public ActionResult GenerateExcelReport(GenerateReportViewModel oGenerateReportViewModel) {
    // Create new excel application
    excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = false;
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    // Excel Generation Code goes here....
    return Json(oGenerateReportViewModel);
}
```

AJAX Call....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmitGenerateRpt").click(function () {
        $("#divLoading").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GenerateReport/GenerateExcelReport',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText + " Thrown Error: " + thrownError + " Options: " + ajaxOptions);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Function Called!!!");
                $("#divLoading").hide();
            },
            async: true,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and putting a break point in your controller method?

Comment: As soon as the action method is called it gives internal Server Error. I debugged the action method and there is nothing wrong there. It creates an excel file and download at at client.

Comment: check your f12 menu on the browser. that will show the response HTML which should give you more error detail.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to pass JSON to your action, you have to pass a string representation of the JSON, typically with JSON.stringify:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    ...
});
```

Or of course, since you're passing nothing, you can just do

```
    data: "{}",
```

If you're using the default `contentType` instead (application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8), then you can pass in a javascript object, and assuming it's a simple object, it will translate that to URL-encoded key-values for your POST contents. For that to work, you'd have to also remove your `processData:false` line.

Comment: That code works (minus the Excel stuff) once you stringify the data, so if you're still getting a 500 after making that change, I'd bet it's with the implementation itself, so you should be able to set a breakpoint in the controller action now. Or at least get some feedback by watching the raw HTTP response in your dev tools.

Comment: But I am not passing any data as controller function gets data from my ViewModel.

Comment: If you want to pass your viewmodel into the AJAX call, then you actually have to pass your viewmodel into the AJAX call in the `data` parameter. Your code is just passing an empty object.